# Sorting sales by year/month descending, salescount desc

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a little problem with sorting out the values from my Nothwind database.
My task is to create a query, that will give me a list of employees and their sales for each month of yeach year, for example:

> EmployeeID  SalesCount  OrdersDate

So far my code looks like this:

```
 SELECT e.EmployeeID, COUNT(*) AS SalesCount, 
        cast(year(OrderDate) as varchar) + '.' + 
        cast(month(OrderDate) as varchar) as OrdersDate
FROM Employees e
LEFT OUTER JOIN Orders o ON o.EmployeeID=e.EmployeeID
GROUP BY e.EmployeeID, YEAR(OrderDate), MONTH(OrderDate)
ORDER BY e.EmployeeID, SalesCount DESC, OrdersDate DESC;
```

But it gives me incorrectly sorted results. What I need is, is a list of EmployeesID, how many sales each one of them did on particular month.

> 1. 23     10.1997
> 2. 15     10.1997
> 3. 10     10.1997

What should I change to get the result I need?

---

Incorrect results

```
1   11  1998.3
1   9   1996.12
1   9   1998.1
1   9   1998.2
1   8   1997.9
1   8   1998.4
```

What I need

```
1   11  1998.3
2   10  1998.3
7   9   1998.3
4   8   1998.3
```

Comment: Don't be shy.  What is the result you need?

Comment: Table structure, data?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Sorry, I didn't explained it too well. I need to group this by date. All employeee's sales in descending order for 10.1997, then for 09.1997 and so on.

Comment: @DT I am using old Northwind database. So far my query gives me correct results, the problem is with grouping/puttign it in the right order.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your `SELECT` statement. I think it should be:

```
SELECT e.EmployeeID, COUNT(*) AS SalesCount, 
    year(OrderDate) AS [Sales year], 
    month(OrderDate) AS [Sales month]
```

and change the order by to:

```
ORDER BY e.EmployeeID, SalesCount DESC
```

Although difficult to show without some sample data and sample output

Comment: With that order, it shows me employee with ID.1 and his sales in descending order, then ID.2 with sales in descending order. I need it to be ordered by sales count and on particular month and year.

Comment: Also that select gives me two different columns, I hoped to have date in one.

Answer (score 0):

It was simplier than I thought. And I've learned that order of conditions is important.

What I had:

```
GROUP BY e.EmployeeID, YEAR(OrderDate), MONTH(OrderDate)
ORDER BY e.EmployeeID, SalesCount DESC, OrdersDate DESC;
```

What I needed to write:

```
GROUP BY e.EmployeeID, YEAR(OrderDate), MONTH(OrderDate)
ORDER BY OrdersDate DESC, SalesCount DESC, e.EmployeeID;
```

Now it shows me this:

```
1   5   1998.5
8   3   1998.5
2   2   1998.5
4   2   1998.5
7   2   1998.5
2   18  1998.4
3   10  1998.4
4   10  1998.4
7   9   1998.4
8   9   1998.4
1   8   1998.4
6   5   1998.4
9   4   1998.4
```

Thank you for your help, you've helped me to find what was wrong!